# Determine the Jacobian matrix for $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2+1}-1$

Tags: calculus, matrices, jacobian

> Determine the Jacobian matrix for $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2+1}-1$

I'm confused because we only have one unknown variable. Usually you have two or more unknowns, something like $f(x,y,z)=..$ mixed function with several variables. Then you determine its Jacobian matrix.

But in this case we only have one variable. So what I would do is actually the same as usual, derivate for $x$ and then that would be our Jacobian matrix?

$$\frac{\vartheta }{\vartheta x}f(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

$$\Rightarrow \text{Jacobian matrix } J_f = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}
\end{pmatrix}$$

Really...?

Comment: It's really  so simple, but your derivative is wrong.

Comment: @EmilioNovati Oh let me correct that quickly!

Comment: @EmilioNovati I hope everything is alright now?

Comment: Yes . I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a function of one variable the Jacobian reduce to the first derivative, that is:
$$
J_f=\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}
$$